# How come I am not able to transfer over const variable to different React file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to transfer a const variable from one file to another. For some reason I can't access it and It is not letting me display it in a text file Below is the homepage.js code and the pay.js file respectively. I am trying to transfer the displayedAmount variable from the homepage file to the pay file and then display it in a text element. But when I do that I get this error "Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component."

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import pay from './pay';

const homepage = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [selectedAmount, setSelectedAmount] = useState("0");
  const [displayedAmount, setDisplayedAmount] = useState("0");
  const fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(0);  // initial opacity
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const buttonWidth = screenWidth * 0.45;
  const spaceBetweenNumbers = 100;
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }
    ).start();
    
    if (selectedAmount.includes('.')) {
        const [whole, decimal] = selectedAmount.split('.');
        setDisplayedAmount(`${isNaN(parseInt(whole)) ? "0" : parseInt(whole).toLocaleString()}.${decimal}`);
      } else {
        setDisplayedAmount(isNaN(parseInt(selectedAmount)) ? "0" : parseInt(selectedAmount).toLocaleString());
      }

    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }
    ).start();

  }, [selectedAmount]);

  const handleNumberPress = (number) => {
    if (selectedAmount.length < 5) {
      setSelectedAmount(prevState => prevState === "0" ? String(number) : prevState + number);
    }
  };

  const handleDecimalPress = () => {
    if (!selectedAmount.includes(".") && selectedAmount.length < 4) {
      setSelectedAmount(prevState => prevState + ".");
    }
  };

  const handleDeletePress = () => {
    setSelectedAmount(prevState => prevState.slice(0, -1) || "0");
  };
  const goTopay = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Pay', { displayedAmount }); // passing displayedAmount as a parameter
  };
```

```
 import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
 import React from 'react';
 import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
 import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
 import homepage from './homepage';
 import displayedAmount from './homepage'
 
 
 const Pay = ({ route, navigation }) => {
     const { displayedAmount } = route.params;
     const goToHome = () => {
     navigation.navigate('Homepage'); // The corrected screen name should be 'Homepage' instead of 'homepage'
   };
 
   return (
     <View>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToHome}>
         <Feather name="x" color="black" size={30} style={styles.cross} />
       </TouchableOpacity>
       <View
   style={{
     borderBottomColor: 'grey',
     borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
     marginTop: 95,
   }}
 />
 <Text style={styles.to}>To</Text>
 <View
   style={{
     borderBottomColor: 'grey',
     borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
     marginTop: 55,
   }}
 />
 <Text style={styles.for}>For</Text>
 <View
   style={{
     borderBottomColor: 'grey',
     borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
     marginTop: 55,
   }}
 />
 <Text>{displayedAmount}</Text> {/* Display the displayedAmount */}
     </View>
     
   );
 };
 
 export default Pay;
 
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   cross: {
     position: 'absolute',
     left: 15,
     top: 50,
   },
   to:{
     fontFamily: 'CashMarketMedium',
     fontSize: 16,
     position: 'absolute',
     left: 19,
     top: 110,
   },
   for:{
     fontFamily: 'CashMarketMedium',
     fontSize: 16,
     position: 'absolute',
     left: 19,
     top: 165,
   },
   line: {
     position: 'absolute',
     left: 15,
     top: 50 + 36 + 4, // To position the line below the 'x' icon, we add its size (36) and some margin (4)
     width: '100%',
     height: 1,
     backgroundColor: 'grey',
   },
 });
```

Comment: This isn't your bug because you're shadowing displayedAmount inside Pay, but your `displayedAmount` isn't exported, and to be exported it would also have to be top-level (not inside a function), which is why you can't import it.

Answer (score 1):

Couple options:

1. For static values export the value in a non-nested `const`. Typically keep your constants separate so you do not create require cycles if two components needs the same constant but one requires the other. FYI Exporting constants are named exports VS default exports. So importing with curly brackets is needed.

```js
//constants file
export const value1 = '123456'

// component file
import { value1 } from '../constants'
```

2. For stateful values that need to be exported across the app, look at React.Context api or a global state management library.
3. For child components you can pass data to components via props.
4. For react-navigation screen navigation you can send params to screen via the params object.